Android emulator gives error on starting in android studio
Android emulator gives error on starting

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:146:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'notGCed'.
notGCed: ignoredLeaks.notGCed.merge(
^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker-10.0.5/lib/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart:130:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const IgnoredLeaks({
^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:193:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'notGCed'.
notGCed: newNotGCed,
^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker-10.0.5/lib/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart:130:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const IgnoredLeaks({
^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:180:35: Error: The getter 'notGCed' isn't defined for the class 'IgnoredLeaks'.


'IgnoredLeaks' is from 'package:leak_tracker/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart' ('/C:/Users/ajoyl/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker-10.0.5/lib/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'notGCed'.
var newNotGCed = ignoredLeaks.notGCed.track([...notGCed, ...classes]);
^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Users\ajoyl\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
The flutter version installed is 3.22.1
PS D:\refereevision> flutter --version
Flutter 3.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a14f74ff3a (3 days ago) • 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
Engine • revision 55eae6864b
Tools • Dart 3.4.1 • DevTools 2.34.3
PS D:\refereevision>
I tried deleting the cache and restarting android studio.

Your problems have nothing to do with the emulator. Please read the error messages and you will see that compilation fails. Hence please correct your question (remove the emulator reference) as this is a pure build problem (if the app does not build of course it can not be started on a device).
